# Need to print outputs to csv files without missing any data

Tags: python, pandas, csv, data-analysis

I am a Pynewbie and am working on a project using apis. I will pitch in to the query directly.
Simply about my Algorithm:
1.Read data one by one from a csv file for input.
2.Use input sample number in 3 different api endpoints and gather the information from it.
3.Print the data in a csv file.
I am attaching the code with this query. I am struggling to get the output into a csv file properly.
Please help me on this.
NOTE: I also need to know how to get only specific outputs from the urls instead of spanning all the outputs

### CODE:

```
def ltostring(jrow): # to convert list input to string to use in urls
    str1 = ""
    for ele in jrow:
        str1 += ele
    return str1
with open("inputfile.csv", 'r') as inputfile: #input file
    csvreader = csv.reader(inputfile)
    for arow in csvreader:
        def sample():
            samplenum = ltostring(arow)
            return samplenum
        snum = sample()
        url1 = "https://api.url.test/api/v1/samples/"+snum
        url2 = "https://api.url.test/api/v1/samples/"+snum+"/info"
        url3 = "https://api.url.test/api/v1/samples/"+snum+"/swversion"
        payload = {}
        headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Basic **********authorization_details*****************'
        }
        resp1 = requests.request("GET", url1, headers=headers, data=payload)
        resp2 = requests.request("GET", url2, headers=headers, data=payload)
        resp3 = requests.request("GET", url3, headers=headers, data=payload)
# converting the outputs into json format
        result1 = json.loads(resp1.text)
        result2 = json.loads(resp2.text)
        result3 = json.loads(resp3.text)
# merging all the outputs into one result
        result = {**result1, **result2, **result3}
```

I have tried csv as well as pandas but the output is not aligned properly.
I either get the information printed multiple rows with confusing data or not receiving the output at all.
Please help me on this as I am nearing my deadline for this project.
Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.